# swift: bold or italic text

Tags: ios, swift

There are some way to edit text inside string or JSON(not in label)? I want to do *italic* or **bold** text inside string. There are some symbols to edit text: `**` or `_` like `\n` `\n\n` to edit line space?

my example in code:

```
textLabel.text = "**my bold text** or _italic_"
```

should be like: **my bold text** or *italic*"

Comment: You need to use `NSAttributedString`. There are different parsers available to translate theses effects, from HTML tags, Markdown tags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to render markdown you got from JSON on a `UILabel`?

There are many pods out there that converts markdown text to `NSAttributedString`. A quick Google search gave me [this](https://github.com/NimbusKit/markdown) and [this](https://github.com/xing/XNGMarkdownParser).

You just read the markdown as text from the JSON using `JSONDecoder` or SwiftyJSON, pass it to the API provided by the pod, get the attributed string, and set it as the `attributedText` of the label:

```
// using the pod from the first link
let parser = NSAttributedStringMarkdownParser()
label.attributedText = parser.attributedString(fromMarkdownString: "_hello_")
```

Comment: I have a lot of text in my JSON and I don't want edit this text in `label.attributedText`. In my code, I have something like this `label.text = json.text` I should add this symbol __ in text in JSON.

Comment: @user291334 so your JSON isn't in markdown, and you want to edit it? Then I recommend you to create an NSAttributedString the way Chris showed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSAttributedString or NSMutableAttributedString classes. The example below will make the text in the UILabel called `myLabel` bold.

```
let myString = "Your text here!"
let fontSize = UIFont.systemFontSize
let myAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttributes)
myLabel.attributedText = myMutableString
```

More information is available in the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring).

---

EDIT: My answer is only a simple demonstration of using attributed strings. The answer by @Sweeper is a much better answer for this situation. Using a pod is much easier than writing the string-parsing code yourself!

Comment: I have JSON and I want change text on bold or italic inside JSON.

Comment: JSON is used for sending hierarchical data. There is no formatting included. You would have to extract the string from the JSON and format it as NSMutableAttributedString. You would not see the bold or italic text until it is displayed somewhere, like on a label. I will edit my answer about extracting the JSON and parsing the string to find the part between two characters.

Comment: The answer by @Sweeper above is the best way to do this!